# How to change the last plotstyle of a list

Tags: plotting

I'm using ListLinePlot to plot a list containing 10 lists, using the default colors:

```
ListLinePlot[myList]
```

I would like to be able to keep the default PlotStyle options for the 9 first lists, but not for the last one. I tried to do:

```
myStyle = Append[Table[{Automatic}, {9}], {Green,Thickness[0.01]}];
ListLinePlot[myList, PlotStyle -> {myStyle}]
```

but all the lists are plotted in {Green,Thickness[0.01]}

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: The problem is just a syntax error. Maybe the question is still useful, to demonstrate how the fonctionality can be achieved ?

Comment: Why don't you use `Show`? That's what it is for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
myList = Sort /@ RandomReal[1, {10, 100}];
myStyle = Append[Table[Automatic, {9}], Directive[{Green, Thickness[0.01]}]]; 
ListLinePlot[myList,  PlotStyle -> myStyle]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

replace {myStyle} by myStyle

```
 myStyle = Append[Table[{Automatic}, {9}], {Green, Thickness[0.01]}];
 ListLinePlot[myList, PlotStyle -> myStyle]
```

Comment: erf so stupid... thanks!

Comment: I would be good if the question was corrected from this problem. Then I delete my answer (don't care the +20 of rep).